# Adjusting the Width of UIView Inside UITableViewCell at Runtime

Tags: ios

I have a UITableViewController with cellForIndexPath method as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BudgetTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BudgetTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Budget *budget = [_budgets objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [cell configure:budget];

    return cell;
}



  @interface BudgetTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
    {

    }

    @property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
    @property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIView *remainingBudgetView;
```

Inside the configure method of cell I do the following:

```
-(void) configure:(Budget *)budget
{
    self.remainingBudgetView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 300);

}
```

The remainingBudgetView is UIView inside the prototype cell in Storyboard. But the above never changes the width and height of the remainingBudgetView. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are your `IBOutlets` connected? Forget that even I asked that :P.

It won't, because the tableviewcells dequeued from the tableview (and not instantiated by using `initWithSomething`) have a default layoutsubviews being called when they are ready to be drawn. So even if you set the frame, the layoutsubviews will override your frame changes and sets it to the default frame you set to the view in the prototype cell in storyboard.

The way out can be to rethink about the problem. Maybe you want your budget view to be a `UILabel` or a set of `UILabels`. You can assign them full width and align text to left or centre as per required. I hope I'm clear.

Comment: Thanks! But I want my remainingBudgetView to be a UIView so I can show a progress bar type of interface. Like a rectangle. The width of the rectangle indicates how much budget is remaining. PS: Outlets are connected.

Comment: Why do you need to declare your `remainingBudgetView` in storyboard? Why can't it be simply something like this in your `-(void) configure:(Budget*)budget { [self.remainingBudgetView removeFromSuperView]; self.remainingBudgetView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)]; }`. There is no requirement of declaring the UIView in storyboard. What do you think?

Comment: Thanks! Originally I tried that but since the UITableViewCells are reused it was messing up the cells whenever the UITableView was scrolling. I will try this approach again. Thanks!

Comment: That can be because you are just adding subview but not removing them. Look at my code once more: I'm removing any previously added subview. Note that if you escape this line, the tableview will maintain a strong pointer to the view and hence will not remove it from the the tablviewcell. So you need to remove the subview yourself and then alloc new object instance.